# A is an NP-Complete language, B is a language in P, prove that A∪B is NP-Complete

Tags: computability, formal-languages, turing-machines

This is the data given in the question:

> - A is an NP-Complete language
> - B is a language in P
> - B ⊆ $A^\complement$
> - $B\ne A^\complement$
>
> Prove that $A\cup$B is NP-Complete.

This is what i tried so far:

This is the venn diagram of the problem as i see it.

[image: VanDiagram of problem]

Now We already know that $A\cup B$ is NP since both A and B are in NP and NP is closed under union.
So we can find a reduction from A to $A\cup B$.

But i could not find any reduction that can satisfy this.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it follows directly that $A \cup B$ is in NP. For a reduction, why not simply reduce $A$?

Decide membership of $A$ as follows:

1. Decide membership of $A \cup B$.
2. Decide membership of $B$.

We only need that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and that $B$ is in $P$, we don't even need the last property (it follows from the others assuming $P \neq NP$).

Comment: So for example, let's say that for a given w we can check if w ∈ B if it is, map it to something else such that w ∉ A ∪ B, if w ∉ B map it directly as is. and because B is in P then we can check if w ∈ B in polynomial time. is that correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I reduced algorithms, not mapped elements. So I gave an algorithm to decide membership of $A$ which is in $P$ assuming that $A \cup B$ is in $P$. Right now I'm not 100% sure how to actually map words, and also not sure why it would be needed.